# Copy a range of two rows to next available blank space

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a window order form to fit a landscape 8x11.5 page.

The rows are set up as follows:
[image]

Each cell has a different data validation dropdown menu.

I'd like to copy this template and paste it below Line #1.
In this case Line #2 would begin at A5.

This code does the trick:

```vb
Sub CopyTemplate()
    Worksheets("WINDOW TEMPLATE").Range("A3:R4").Copy Range("A5:R6")
End Sub
```

The job is done but I'd have to create a macro for each new line manually.

Is there a way to replace the destination range with a variable that will find the next available empty row to create Line 2?
Like
[image]

In the case of Line 2 it would be A7 (and then every two lines would be the loop I guess).

I've seen several examples similar to mine but I'm too inexperienced to retrofit the code. As I understand it, `.End` finds the next blank cell but all it seems to do is goto the bottom of the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the last numbered item in Col A then move down two rows:

```vb
Sub CopyTemplate()
    Dim c as range
    
    With Worksheets("WINDOW TEMPLATE")
        Set c = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2) 'move down two rows from last numbered item
        .Range("A3:R4").Copy c
        c.value = c.offset(-2).value + 1 'increment item#
    End With
End Sub
```